# How to use Html Agility Pack with windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, html-agility-pack

First of all I want to say that I am new to c# and Windows 8 apps. So, please, don't be hard on me.

I have the following code to extract some images urls and to save them in a XML file.
I am using Html Agility Pack, but when I try to use the code with a Windows 8 application it doesn't work. I know that I have to use the Fizzler Html Agility Pack from here: http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/releases/view/89833 but I don't know what is wrong.
I am using visual studio 2012 and it does not recognize the following elements:

```
***WebClient*** x = new ***WebClient***();  
***XmlDocument*** output = new ***XmlDocument***();  
***XmlElement*** imgElements = output.CreateElement("ImgElements");  
foreach(HtmlNode link in document.***DocumentElement***.SelectNodes("//img[contains(@src, '_412s.jpg')]"));                                             
***out***.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
```

Code:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Xml;

public void Images()
{
    WebClient x = new WebClient();
    string source = x.DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com");
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.Load(source);
    XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement imgElements = output.CreateElement("ImgElements");
    output.AppendChild(imgElements);
    foreach(HtmlNode link in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img[contains(@src, '_412s.jpg')]"))
    {
        XmlElement img = output.CreateElement(link.Name);
        foreach(HtmlAttribute a in link.Attributes)
        {
            img.SetAttribute(a.Name, a.Value);
        }
        imgElements.AppendChild(img);
    }
    out.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
}
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com") };
var r = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
string html;
if (r.IsSuccessStatusCode) html = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
```

Should be:

```
output.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
```

And then you need to add the following two namespaces to then top of the code file:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
```

These errors have nothing to do with Windows 8.  They would be errors in any version.  I'm not sure why you'd need to switch from the `WebClient` class to the `HttpClient` class, since they are both supported in Windows 8, but, if you want to use the `HttpClient` class, something like this should work:

```
HttpClient x = new HttpClient();
Task<string> t = x.GetStringAsync(@"http://www.google.com");
t.Wait();
string source = t.Result;
```

Comment: I had to change out.Save to outline.Save . WebClient isn't recognized in windows 8 apps so I changed it with HttpClient, but now DownloadString isn't working anymore. I think I have to change it with client.GetAsync. I also had to change DocumentElement with DocumentNode. Can you please help me with the GetAsync function ?